# ngjstree: error when select node automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstree

I'm using NgJsTree (https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree) for create a tree. I would like that the option choose by user was saved; so I'm saving the user's choice and the full path in a pair of variable. In particular case, I get the full path like this `data.instance.get_path(data.node,'/');` and the selected node in this way `data.instance.get_node(data.selected[i])`

I trigger the `loaded` event with this function:

```
openSelectedNode = function(e, data){
    var nodes = config.path.split("/");
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
        $(this).jstree("open_node", $('#' + nodes[i].replace(" ", "")));
    }
    $(this).jstree('select_node', $('#' + nodes[nodes.length-1] ));
}
```

So in this way, when the tree is load, I can reopen the tree and select the correct node. The code works, but in console I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parents' of undefined
```

It isn't the right approach? Am i doing any errors?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be calling node.parents somewhere, which happened to me. Also, I would approach your problem different.
I would:

- Use the instance provided by ngJStree to reference the tree, and then use

  `var selectedNode = vm.treeInstance.jstree(true).get_selected();`
- Store that nodes id, then set its state to "selected: true" before you create the the tree the next time. It should be already selected that way.

Comment: Thanks for replay, i will try this approach.